# Python - Speeding up Web Scraping using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, selenium

I have the following function to scrape a webpage.

```
def parse(link: str, list_of_samples: list, index: int) -> None:
    # Some code to scrape the webpage (link is given)
    # The code will generate a list of strings, say sample
    list_of_samples[index] = sample
```

I have another script that calls the above script for all URLs present in a list

```
def call_that_guy(URLs: list) -> list:
    samples = [None for i in range(len(URLs))]
    for i in range(len(URLs)):
        parse(URLs[i], samples, i)
    return samples
```

Some other function that calls the above function

```
def caller() -> None:
    URLs = [url_1, url_2, url_3, ..., url_n]
    # n will not exceed 12
    samples = call_thay_guy(URLs)
    print(samples)

# Prints the list of samples, but is taking too much time
```

One thing I noticed is that the parse function is taking around 10s to parse a single webpage (I am using Selenium). So, parsing all the URLs present in the list, it is taking around 2 minutes. I want to speed it up, probably using multithreading.

I tried doing the following instead.

```
import threading

def call_that_guy(URLs: list) -> list:
    threads = [None for i in range(len(URLs))]
    samples = [None for i in range(len(URLs))]
    for i in range(len(URLs)):
        threads[i] = threading.Thread(target = parse, args = (URLs[i], samples, i))
        threads[i].start()
    return samples
```

But, when I printed the returned value, all of its contents were None.

What am I trying to Achieve:

I want to asynchronously Scrape a list of URLs and populate the list of samples. Once the list is populated, I have some other statements to execute (they should execute only after samples is populated, else they'll cause Exceptions). I want to scrape the list of URLs faster (asynchronously is allowed) instead of scraping them one after another.

[image]

(I can explain something more clearly with image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use `concurrent.futures` module?

Here is a very simple but super fast code using `concurrent.futures`:

```
import concurrent.futures


def scrape_url(url):
    print(f'Scraping {url}...')
    scraped_content = '<html>scraped content!</html>'
    return scraped_content

urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.facebook.com', 'https://www.youtube.com']
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    results = executor.map(scrape_url, urls)

print(list(results))
# Expected output:
# ['<html>scraped content!</html>', '<html>scraped content!</html>', '<html>scraped content!</html>']
```

If you want to learn threading, I recommend watching this short tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU

Also note that this is not multiprocessing, this is multithreading and the two are not the same. If you want to know more about the difference, you can read this article: https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, I also want to preserve the order of returned values. Formally, for your example, I want the content of google.com, followed by that of facebook.com so on ..
Will it preserve the order?

Comment: Hey, Yes it absolutely keeps the same order as `urls` list. Please accept the answer if it is correct. Thanks.